# D3 Stacked bar chart with different stack level

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Is it possible to build a stacked bar chart in D3 with different stacked levels?

I've been reading about it but cud only find examples which has same stacked levels.

In other words, 
Instead of this JSON -

```
var layers = [
      {
        "name": "apples",
        "values": [
            { "x": 0, "y": 11},
            { "x": 1, "y": 10},
            { "x": 2, "y": 10}
        ]
      },
      {  
        "name": "oranges",
        "values": [
          { "x": 0, "y": 9},
          { "x": 1, "y": 9},
          { "x": 2, "y": 9}
        ]
      }
    ];
```

Can we create a bar chart with -

```
var layers = [
      {
        "name": "apples",
        "values": [
            { "x": 0, "y": 11},
            { "x": 1, "y": 10},
            { "x": 2, "y": 10}
        ]
      },
      {  
        "name": "oranges",
        "values": [
          { "x": 0, "y": 9}
        ]
      }
    ];
```

I read - 
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1134768

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Stack-Layout

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly easy to do, depending on how you design your loading of data into the chart.

Essentially the process would be:

1. Use the `data()` function with the layers variable, which allows you to then work with each data set individually
2. Add a `g` element using the `enter()` function of the result of step 1
3. Call `data()` again, this time using the `values` of the attached data (`.data(function(d){return d.values;})`)
4. Use the `enter()` function of the result of step 3 to generate the bars

Note that to get things to actually stack you will need to keep track of the current stacked height of each x position. All you have to do is generate an array of zeroes and update the value at index `d.x` when setting the rectangle's `y` attribute.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/armarchm/hk2tp8kL/) showing a quick sample. To make this a fully working example, you'll have to add axes/scales and all the extra things.

Comment: hey, thanks for the help.. I missed it when I saw it first. so its basically doing the same thing.. It is stacking all the x:0's x:1's and x:2's ... thats not what I want... I want to stack values of oranges in one stacked bar...

Comment: in the sample input above, I'd like to have 2 stacked bars, one with 11, 10 and 10 while other with just one value 9. 
In your code, there are 3 stacked bars, one with 11 and 9, other with 10 and again last with 10.