# Create a stacked bar chart with different stack level

Tags: d3.js, vue.js, stacked-chart

this code is inside a VUEJs framwork.

I am working to create a stacked bar chart but wasn't able to use D3 stack function.
so i tried implementing y position and height of rectangles in a different way.

This is the data I have:

```js
tasks: [
  {
    name:t1,
    taskTotal:1000
    taskStages: [
       { 
        stageTotal: 200 
       },
       { 
        stageTotal: 400 
       },{ 
        stageTotal: 400 
       }
    ]
    
  },
  {
    name:t2,
    taskTotal:500
    stages:[
          { 
            stageTotal: 200 
          },
          {
            stageTotal: 300
          }
    ],
  }
]
```

I have tried to make scales specific for each task, but wasn't successful.

the x pos of each Bar is fine, my issue is with y pos of the rectangle and height.

this is the code i currently have:

```js
getScaleForTask(task){
  return d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0,this.svgHeight - 20])
    .domain([0,task.taskTotal])
},


TaskCumulativeTotal(taskStages){
  const arrOFCumulativeSums = [0]
   taskStages.reduce((sumOfStages,currStage) => {
       arrOFCumulativeSums.push(currStage.stageTotal + sumOfStages)
       return currStage.stageTotal + sumOfStages;
     },0);
  return arrOFCumulativeSums
},
    
chartBuilder(){
  let currCumulativeSum;
  let yScaleForTask;

  
  const taskG = svg
          .selectAll('g')
          .data(this.tasks)
          .enter()
          .append('g')
          .attr(
            'transform',
            (d, i) => `translate(${cunmulativeGroupXPos[i]},0)`,
          );
          
  // from here i'm stuck
  const stageG = taskG
          .selectAll('g')
          .data(d =>{ 
              yScaleForTask = this.getScaleForTask(d);
              currCumulativeSum = this.TaskCumulativeTotal(d.taskStages); 
              return d.taskStages; 
            })
          .enter()
          .append('g')
          .attr('transform', d => xScale(d.taskName)); // this determins the x pos

        stageG
          .append('rect')
          .attr('width', 30)
          .attr('y', (d,i) => yScaleForTask(currCumulativeSum[i]))
          .attr('height', d => yScaleForTask(d.stageTotal))
          .attr('fill', (d, i) => (i % 2 === 0 ? '#66ccff' : '#99ff66'))
          .attr('stroke', 'grey');
 }
```

This is how it currently looks
[image]

I've been trying to make each task stage to stack on each other,
I did read [D3 Stacked bar chart with different stack level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36162958/d3-stacked-bar-chart-with-different-stack-level)

and 
https://bl.ocks.org/DimsumPanda/689368252f55179e12185e13c5ed1fee

Comment: can you post the working code, to make it easyer to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to make it work: posting the code for future reference.

they way I solved this was to iterate over the tasks and for each task add a group and inside each group add the bars.

this way i didn't lose the cumulative sums which i needed for the y position.

```js
    chartBuilder() {
    
      const longestTask = this.getLongestTask();
      const taskNames = this.tasks.map(t => t.taskName);
      const xScale = d3.scaleBand()
        .domain(taskNames)
        .rangeRound([0, this.svgWidth]);
      const svg = d3.select('#stacked-svg-tasks');
      const yScaleForTask = this.getScaleForTask(this.svgHeight - 20, longestTask);

      const barWidthScale = Math.round(this.svgWidth / this.tasks.length) - this.GbGS;
      // adding data to show as bar chart
      this.tasks.forEach((task, taskIndex) => {
        const currCumulativeSum = this.CumulativeTimeOfStages(task.taskStages);
        const data = [task];

        const currTask = svg
          .selectAll(`bar${taskIndex}`)
          .data(data)
          .enter()
          .append('g')
          .attr('class', `bar${taskIndex}`)
          .attr(
            'transform',
            `translate(${xScale(task.taskName)},0)`,
          )
          .selectAll('rect')
          .data(d => d.taskStages)
          .enter()
          .append('rect')
          .attr('y', (d, i) => this.svgHeight - yScaleForTask(currCumulativeSum[i]))
          .attr('width', barWidthScale)
          .attr('height', d => yScaleForTask(d.totalTime))
          .attr('fill', (d, i) => (i % 2 === 0 ? '#66ccff' : '#99ff66'));
      });
```