# Stacked Bar Chart With Different Stacked Bars For Each Bar

Tags: javascript, highcharts, visualization

I'm working on a stacked bar chart for a database of products that have been categorized into each function of the product and subfunctions.

For example:

Communication: Subfunctions: ["Talking", "Hearing", "Captioning"]
Navigation: Subfunctions: ["GPS", "Directions"]

I have this data in this form:

```
{'Function': {'Sub1': 69.0,
  'Sub2': 17.0,
  'Sub3': 3.0,
  'Sub4': 0.0},
 'Function2': {'Sub1': 41.0,
  'Sub2': 49.0,
  'Sub3': 48.0,
  'Sub4': 32.0},
 'Function3': {'Sub1': 9.0,
  'Sub2': 11.0,
  'Sub3': 19.0,
  'Sub4': 10.0,
  'Sub5': 0.0,
  'Sub6': 0.0},
 ...and so on}
```

The bar chart shows each function (communication, navigation, etc.) as a bar with the sub-bars as each subfunction. I'm trying to find a way to visualize this chart in Highcharts, but have only found barcharts that are consistent across all bars. I found a post from July that seemed to approach this, but all the demos were broken so I'm not sure.

I was able to do this in Python using Matplotlib, but I hope to transfer this to a web based visualization in Highcharts. In particular, it required isolating the labels ("Sub1", "Sub2", etc.) to a separate list and transforming the above dictionary into:

```
{
'Function1': [69.0, 17.0, 3.0, 0.0],
...etc
}
```

and then separately referring to the above dictionary for the Subfunction names using indexing (which feels like a very wrong solution, despite being relatively functional, since it requires many copies of data).

I took a look at [D3 Stacked bar chart with different stack level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36162958/d3-stacked-bar-chart-with-different-stack-level), but it seems to use a different data schema and have a slightly different goal than mine. In the linked question, it seems like their data has categories shared across bars, and also uses D3 instead of Highcharts.

I've attached a photo example of what I'm looking to do, though I'm also interested in fixing the color scheme.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFmsS.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible to achieve with Highcharts by using the `series.stack` option and by properly parsed data. You will also need to include some additional settings for styling. Here is my proposition of the code:

```
let data = {
      'Function1': {
        'A': 1,
        'B': 2,
        'C': 3,
      },
      'Function2': {
        'D': 3,
        'E': 4,
        'F': 1,
      },
      'Function3': {
        'G': 1,
        'H': 5,
        'I': 2,
      }
    };
    
    
    function parseData(data) {
      let parsedData = [],
        keys = Object.keys(data),
        numOfFunctions = keys.length;
    
      for (let i = 0; i < numOfFunctions; i++) {
        let currentFunction = data[keys[i]],
          currentFunctionKeys = Object.keys(currentFunction),
          numOfKeys = currentFunctionKeys.length;
    
        for (let j = 0; j < numOfKeys; j++) {
          let dataArray = [];
    
          for (let k = 0; k < numOfFunctions; k++) {
            dataArray.push(k === i ? currentFunction[currentFunctionKeys[j]] : null);
          }
    
          parsedData.push({
            name: currentFunctionKeys[j],
            data: dataArray,
            stack: keys[i]
          });
        }
      }
    
      return parsedData;
    }
    
    
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
      chart: {
        type: 'column'
      },
      xAxis: {
        categories: Object.keys(data)
      },
    
      plotOptions: {
        column: {
          grouping: false,
          stacking: 'normal'
        }
      },
        
        legend: {
        enabled: false
        },
    
      series: parseData(data)
    });
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wxp5g06L/

API reference:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.stack